# Delete Rows in Excel based on data in one cell

Tags: powershell

Is there a way in Powershell to delete an entire row based on the value found in one cell in Excel.

Scenario:

I have a list of samaccountnames in column H.  I have vetted that 100's of these accounts no longer exist in AD.  I would like to delete all rows that contain these non existent samaccountnames in Column H.

I was thinking I could throw the samaccountnames in a text file and use get-content, but I am unsure what needs to be done for the excel part.

Comment: What is the file type?  *.xlsx?  *.csv?  Other?

Comment: The file type is .csv

Answer (score 2):

Updated (thanks below comment)

I think you are looking something like that, I give you a draft and you have to custom for you :

```
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\excel.xls")
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item(1)

for ($i = $worksheet.usedrange.rows.count; $i -gt 0; $i--)
{ 
    $user = $worksheet.Range("H$i").Text

    if (dsquery user -samid $user)
    {
        $found = $true
    }
    else
    {
        $found = $false
    }

    if (!($found))
    {
        $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, $i).EntireRow.Delete()
    }
}

$WorkBook.SaveAs($file)
$WorkBook.Close($true)
$objExcel.Quit()
```

Comment: This is going to miss things, because when it deletes a row the row below it shifts up and the `For` loop moves down at the same time. So say `$i = 6` and you delete Row 6. Row 7 moves up, becoming the new Row 6. The `For` loop then moves on to `$i = 7` which looks at the new Row 7 (which before the last deletion was previously Row 8). The original Row 7 is never looked at.

Comment: Actually, your theory is sound, you just need to work from the bottom up. `For($i = $worksheet.usedrange.rows.count;$i -gt 0;$i--){` what you have is a little different than what I'd do, but it should function fine once you change it to work from the bottom up.

Comment: I need to be able to load a txt file that has the samaccountnames to check for in Column H.  I do not see where in the above script I can do this.

Comment: You don't need an extra file for that I think, I updated the code please check.