# Delete excel rows based on a specific value with Powershell

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I found some similar solutions to my issue here, but they do not exactly cover my problem and since I'm still very new to Powershell, I couldn't modify them specifically for my use case. Therefore I have a question.

I am making a weekly manual Excel export (.xlsx) from a system, which doesn't offer any filtering options. The result is a table with around 500 entries.

My goal here is to write a powershell script, which automatically deletes/removes ALL rows, containing a value DIFFERENT from "01.01.2099" in the "Valid until" column (F1 in the Excel-Sheet).

[image]

I still haven't written any code, since I'm not sure where or how to start here. I'm sure this is a very simple task and any help from a more experienced *Powersheller* will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete Rows in Excel based on data in one cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441410/delete-rows-in-excel-based-on-data-in-one-cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest challenge here is that you need to test if a cell contains a certain **date** value or not.
From your image, you can see the dates are formatted in different ways, so comparing the cell's value to a date in a specific format is tricky.
Luckily, the `DateTime` object has a static method `FromOADate()` that can do the conversion for you.

Also, you need to delete rows from bottom to top row, otherwise by deleting a row, the index of the ones below that is changed because they all move up one row.

```
$file  = 'D:\Test\Export.xlsx'
# create a datetime variable to chack against
$checkDate = [datetime]::new(2099, 1, 1)   # or do (Get-Date -Year 2099 -Month 1 -Day 1).Date

$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
# open the Excel file
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet    = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
# get the number of rows in the sheet
$rowMax   = $sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

# loop through the rows to test if the value in column 6 is date 01/01/2099
# do the loop BACKWARDS, otherwise the indices will change on every deletion.
for ($row = $rowMax; $row -ge 2; $row--) {
    # convert the formatted date in the cell to real DateTime object with time values set all to 0
    # Column 6 is the 'Valid until' column
    $cellDate = [datetime]::FromOADate($sheet.Cells.Item($row, 6).Value2).Date
    if ($cellDate -ne $checkDate) {
        $null = $sheet.Rows($row).EntireRow.Delete()
    }
}

# save and exit
$workbook.Close($true)
$excel.Quit()
# clean up the COM objects used
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

---

In the above code, the column index is hardcoded to be 6
If you aren't sure about that, but do know the columns name, you can insert this snippet:

```
# get the column index for column named 'Valid until'
$colMax = $sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
for ($col = 1; $col -le $colMax; $col++) {
    if ($sheet.Cells.Item(1, $col).Value() -eq 'Valid until') { break }  # assuming the first row has the headers
}
```

above the `$rowMax = $sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` line and inside the loop change `$sheet.Cells.Item($row, 6).Value2` into `$sheet.Cells.Item($row, $col).Value2`